# Why does modal pop up pressing space bar press? How do I prevent it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I have an action planned on a space bar click. It does happen.

```
// when space bar is pressed
do-something; // Applied on the $(document).keypress..
```

But, when I press space bar, along with the event/action that has to be triggered, modal load/shows up again. Why is it so? I have tried to prevent modal from loading again :

```
$('#goal').on('hidden.bs.modal',function() {
            $(document).focus(); // Get the button that triggered modal
                                 // out of focus                            

});
```

But the document, doesn't get focus and the button that triggered modal-load remains in focus until I click on the screen to bring the document back to focus. How could I prevent modal from loading again on space bar press?

I also tried the `blur()` function on button that triggers modal. But it doesn't help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `$(document).focus();` will have no effect, because `document` is not a focusable element, it's actually not an element at all. Try using `document.activeElement` to get the active element and `blur` it.

```
document.activeElement.blur();
```

To do this, you will need to listen for the event when the modal is closed, `hidden.bs.modal`, since Bootstrap will automatically return the focus to the button on close.

### Example ([Live](http://www.bootply.com/PbcEH23byE)):

```
$(document).on('hidden.bs.modal', function() {
    document.activeElement.blur();
});
```

Alternately, you could set the focus to a focusable element in the model itself if one exists. This would probably give the most-pleasant user experience.

Comment: Didn't help. Here is the jsfiddle : http://www.bootply.com/p9Bp7UurpP After the modal is closed, the button remains in focus.

Comment: so when the space bar is pressed, modal loads again! I don't want this to happen.

Comment: I had tried this, but with `$('#myModal')` instead of `$(document)`. Could you explain the difference?

Comment: @SuhailGupta The event callback on the element itself runs before Bootstrap returns focus to the element. Setting the event higher in the tree circumvents this.

Answer (score 1):

It might be due to default focus on an element which might be causing this. Tried event.preventDefault(); ?

```
// when space bar is pressed
event.preventDefault();
do-something; // Applied on the $(document).keypress..
```

Comment: Yes. Let this be a comment.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit hard to answer without seeing more of your code or, even better, a jsfiddle that demonstrates your problem.

But in general, you can prevent the space bar keypress from having any side effects by returning `false` from the jquery event handler function to indicate that you've consumed the event.

So (guessing what your event handler looks like)

```
$('...').keypress( function(event) {
  if ( event.which == 32 ) {
    doSomething();
    return false;
  }
});
```

Hope this helps. If not, please give a bit more details.

Comment: Here is the jsfiddle : http://www.bootply.com/p9Bp7UurpP When the modal is closed the button `launch demo model` remains in focus. On pressing the space bar, modal again pops-up

Comment: I cannot return `false` since I have defined a handler on space bar press. it pauses/resumes the video on the document. Though the handler works fine, but also loads a modal on space bar press

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid the button gaining focus this way:

```
$('#yourButtonId').focus(function(){
  $(this).blur();
});
```

I tried this in the jsFiddle you posted and it works, the space bar doesn't open the modal anymore.